# What is the difference between north and south magnetic poles at the atomic level?

Tags: magnetic-fields, atomic-physics, conventions

How does the electron spin affect the magnet property?  And how do magnets work at the atomic level?

Answer (score 0):

A natural magnet is made up of molecules that have a natural polarity.

One side of the molecule is charged and the other side is the opposite charge.

This is due to the atomic bonding and how the atoms build up the molecule.

The molecule of a natural magnet is a small molecule magnet, and all the molecules have a dipole moment due to their polarity.

The dipole moment of all the molecules is arranged in one way because of the magnetic field of the Earth. This arrangement needs a lot of time.

Though the alignment of the dipoles comes from the interactions between the molecules (as per comment), the molecules like the magnets align themselves (in direction) according to the Earth's magnetic field, this was the same for the first magnetized stone.

Comment: The dipole moments in a natural permanent magnet do arrange largely in one direction, but that is not due to Earth's magnetic field.  It is due to the interactions between the dipoles.  The *direction* to which they align might be influenced by Earth's field, but the *fact* that they align does not.

Comment: So north pole is negative or positive and if dipoles cancel each other the remaining charge would be at corners right?

Comment: I think at the molecule level, id dipoles cancel out, it will not have a charge. You can think of macro objects, where there might be remaining charges at the corner.